# What should I call the symbol “|”？A pipe or bit operator

Tags: python, operator-keyword, naming

Just see the following:

```
def update_page_info(url):
    # fetch_page -> parse_page -> store_page
    chain = fetch_page.s(url) | parse_page.s() | store_page_info.s(url)
    chain()

@app.task()
def fetch_page(url):
    return myhttplib.get(url)

@app.task()
def parse_page(page):
    return myparser.parse_document(page)

@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def store_page_info(info, url):
    PageInfo.objects.create(url=url, info=info)
```

Comment: The *character* is the pipe or vertical bar, the *operation* is the bitwise or, so I tend to call it a pipe unless I'm specifically talking about the operation

Comment: @NickA Could you give a link where I can learn more about the operation?I just feel  confused for not seeing it in tutorial,only bitwise operator is introduced.

Comment: see @Martijn's answer, he links to some useful resources, I'd especially check the second link labelled "binary bitwise operator"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a pipe *character* (more correctly called the [*vertical bar* character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar)), which when used in an expression is called a [binary bitwise operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations):

> The `|` operator yields the bitwise (inclusive) OR of its arguments, which must be integers.

The operator is hookable via the [`__or__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__), which is what SQLAlchemy uses to build queries, as seen in your example code (in contrast to the [boolean `or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), which can't be hooked into due to its short-circuiting behaviour).

Comment: Note the character is called the pipe because it was originally used for piping commands together in Unix

Comment: The operator is hookable via the __or__ special method. Could you elaborate on the meaning of this line?

Comment: So the usage is not a python definition?

Comment: @NM: In the expression `a | b`, Python looks for `type(a).__or__` and calls that, passing in `b`, if it exists. This allows objects to alter how the operator is handled (there is a reverse `__ror__` too, if `type(a).__or__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`, `type(b).__ror__` is tried too).

Comment: @Assassin: of course it is a Python definition; it's all Python code. But the operation has been hooked to fit SQLAlchemy's specific use cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So it is the same to other programming language about the operation?

Comment: @Assassin I'm not sure I understand your question; your English isn't entirely correct leaving me to guess at the exact meaning. Different programming languages will have different semantics and may or may not allow overloading the operator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your patience,that's what I want.